# How to define a GLM for repeated measures anova

Tags: r, anova, measure

I have data in the following format:

[image: data image]

```
afex::aov_car(AVERAGEOFINDICATOR~ 1 Error(id/(YEAR)), data =mydata)
```

I need to check if the indicators and their average are significant over time or not. Is this model correct? What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: You could do this with a linear model `lm(AVERAGEOFINDICATORs ~ YEAR, data = df)` to see if there is a difference between years. Your data doesn't support a mixed effects model.

Comment: Please simply copy and paste your data to the question and remove all **images**. Alternatively(preferably), please provide sample data with `dput`.

Comment: Thank you so much! And @Paul, if my data would  support mixed effect, how would you define it? Just multiypliyng variables?

Comment: @Bazikstano you would need to have id's across multiple repeat-measures (i.e. times).